# programmatically changing references in *.csproj and packages.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio

fetched all the *.csproj and packages.config files and wondering what would be best way to update references

```
 var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".csproj") || s.EndsWith("packages.config")).ToList();


<Reference Include="MyDev.Something">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\Packages\MyDev.Something.1.0\lib\net45\MyDev.Something.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

I would like to change 1.0 to 2.0

Answer (score 3):

`.csproj` and `.config` are xml files. They are easy to process using linq2xml.

```
XNamespace ns = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var xml = XElement.Load(file);

    var nodes = xml.Descendants(ns + "Reference")
        .Where(r => r.Attribute("Include").Value.Contains("MyDev.Something"));

    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var hintPath = node.Element(ns + "HintPath");

        if (hintPath.Value.Contains("MyDev.Something.1.0"))                
            hintPath.Value = hintPath.Value.Replace(
                "MyDev.Something.1.0", "MyDev.Something.2.0");
    }

    xml.Save(file); // First make a backup!
}
```